# Linked style doesn't work for buttons

Tags: gtk, vala, programming

[image: Only button with label has linked style]

Only button with label has linked style.

```
var button_box = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0);
button_box.get_style_context ().add_class (Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_LINKED);

info_button = new Gtk.Button.from_icon_name ("dialog-information-symbolic", Gtk.IconSize.LARGE_TOOLBAR);
button_box.add (info_button);

button_with_label = new Gtk.Button.with_label (_("Test"));
button_box.add (button_with_label);

header_bar.pack_start (button_box);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Gtk.HeaderBar` provides special styling for `Gtk.Button`'s so that they look good inside it.

## The solution:

In your case the solution is easy: remove the `image-button` style class from the `info_button`:
`info_button.get_style_context ().remove_class ("image-button");`

If you have any problems with Gtk styling further on, I recommend to enable Gtk Inspector (read more here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector) which will provide you with great tools to enable / disable Gtk properties and such.